# Which countries apply one-tiered system or two-tiered system in implementing CBDC?

Tags: currency, sovereignty, cryptocurrency

Central Bank Digital Currrency (CBDC) has been proliferated since 2014. Since then, some countries have implemented the one-tiered system or two-tiered system in management.

**One-tiered** system is that the central bank takes charge of issuance and intermediary (account management, transaction verification) regarding CBDC

**Two-tiered** system is that the central bank takes charge of issuance CBDC  while intermediary (account management, transaction verification) is taken charged by commercial banks and other financial institutions.

From what I read so far, Cambodia is the country has already implemented one-tiered system for CBDC management ([here](https://soramitsu.co.jp/bakong/whitepaper))

China is the country which already followed two-tiered system ([here](http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4157443/4293696/2021071614584691871.pdf))

I am looking for what countries already implemented their CBDC and which system (one-tiered or two-tiered) they follow (with references)